# Drop-down menu of Dojo do not open up in QtWeb browser

Tags: qt, webkit, dojo, drop-down-menu

I am using QtWeb browser ([www.qtweb.net](http://www.qtweb.net)) for my development. When I try to open the following URL in the browser, the drop-down menus of the buttons do not open up:
http://archive.dojotoolkit.org/nightly/dojotoolkit/dijit/tests/form/test_Button.html

This issue is not seen across other browsers.

Any workarounds/suggestions/ideas would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the same problem. Interestingly, the popup menus do not work since version 1.7.1.
This is not bug of dojo. This is some mistake in QtWebKit. The problem in touchpad device that defined by default in precomiled qt webkit libs (even if the touchpad does not exists physically).

1. Temporary solution is to edit dojo/has.js file (find this lines in dojo >= 1.7.1):

   ```
   if(has("host-browser")){
       var agent = navigator.userAgent;
       has.add("dom-addeventlistener", !!document.addEventListener);
       has.add("touch", "ontouchstart" in document);        <<<<< Comment this line
       has.add("device-width", screen.availWidth || innerWidth);
       has.add("agent-ios", !!agent.match(/iPhone|iP[ao]d/));
       has.add("agent-android", agent.indexOf("android") > 1);
   }
   ```
2. Here another solution (more painfully):
   [Link to the helpful message source](http://qt-project.org/forums/viewthread/1643)
   You must recompile QtWebKit with DEFINES+=ENABLE_TOUCH_EVENTS=0 that defined in WebCore/features.pri.
   Then you qt web projects will be work properly!